# Reset completed achievements in Game Centre

Tags: ios, swift, game-center, achievements

I am debugging code for achievements in my sprite kit game. When you gain an achievement it goes immediately to 100% achieved - they are one off achievements where you have done a specific thing. The game has NOT been released on the app store.
While doing so I have (somehow) accidentally reported to Game Centre that all my achievements have been completed. To continue debugging I need to reset the achievements to the un-achieved status.

Is there a way to do this?

I know there is resetAchievements(completionHandler: ((Error?) -> Void)?  but that just resets percentages of partially completed achievements.

I have 10 achievements at the moment so if there’s no possibility to reset completed achievements then I’ll need to make 10 more, which is tedious, and test them using increments in percentages instead